# CSS styling in MVC to display different @Html.ActionLink links

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

In an MVC application, I need to display links rendered by @Html.ActionLink as buttons. I have the following code in site.css:

```
.linkbutton {
       font-family: Constantia, Georgia, serif;
       text-align:justify;
       padding-left: 22px;
       background-color:#FF7F00;  
       color:#fff;     
       border: 1px solid #333;
       cursor: pointer;
       font-size:1.2em;       
       width: auto;
       height:auto;        
}
```

In the view I used a table layout for the links and referred the linkbutton class as:

```
  <td class="linkbutton">
      @Html.ActionLink("Add Cab", "Create")
   </td>
```

The link is using the styles from the .linkbutton class. However, the text color that needs to be in white (#fff) is not inherited, despite being defined as color:#fff; in the CSS. Instead the default blue link color with an underline is getting displayed. I need the link to appear with white font color and without the underline.

In CSS I tried:

```
 a.linkbutton.link {
     /*Style code*/
 }
```

Then refer it from the view as:

```
 Html.ActionLink("Add Cab", "Create", new {@class = "linkbutton"}).
```

But, it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Try setting  color:#fff !important;

Comment: Try a { color:inherit; }. Note `a.linkbutton.link` does not exist - it would be `.linkbutton a {..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the rules for links inside `.linkbutton` element, so instead of

```
a.linkbutton.link {
    /*Style code*/
}
```

write

```
.linkbutton a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```